# Magento 2 : How to add free item automatically to the cart

Tags: magento2, module, free-gift

In Magento 2 after I created a **free gift promo it will not add the free item to the cart automatically**.

*Users need to do that manually.* 
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: review the third party extension it may be help [Click](https://amasty.com/free-gift-for-magento-2.html)

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=Free%20Gift%20&ext_platform=Magento%202&sortBy=m2_cloud_prod_default_products_ext_average_rating_desc